# I need to get Round Robin working and yet it doesn't work properly

Tags: c, scheduler, rounding

I'm trying to get a round robin scheduler working properly and unfortunately, despite bloody tears having been spilled, it still seems to bug somewhere in my code. Here's my function:

```
//function that processes the head of the CPU queue (RR version)
int process2 (NodePtr *headcpu, NodePtr *tailcpu, int *count, int timeslice) {

   NodePtr temp2;
   NodePtr temp3;

    (*headcpu)->cpu_time = (*headcpu)->cpu_time - timeslice;

    (*count) = (*count) + timeslice;

  //if statement starts
      if ((*headcpu)->cpu_time <= 0){

         temp3 = dequeue_cpu(headcpu, tailcpu);

         print_result (temp3, count);//call to print_result function

      }//if statement ends

   //else statement starts
     else {

         temp2 = *headcpu;
         *headcpu = (*headcpu)->next;
         (*tailcpu)->next = temp2;
         *tailcpu = temp2;
         (*tailcpu)->next = NULL;

      }//else statement ends

   return 0;//successful termination

}//end process2 function
```

And this is my output:

```
3788   230   31

5001   401   39

5002   402   41

7979   461   63

7919   461   65

1008   72   75

3784   230   87

5000   400   97

7999   456   111

7909   458   115

7989   460   117

7929   462   119


Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

This output has been produced using a 36 sample-long test file and as you can see, only a few values seem to be printed and incorrectly so. And I got a segfault.

Can someone please identify the source of the problem?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to SO. Please do keep in mind that we don't debug code on request here. Launch your debugger and isolate the problem to a single line. Also, make sure you visit [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask questions on SO.

Comment: I did: apparently, it's having issues with (*headcpu)->cpu_time = (*headcpu)->cpu_time - timeslice. I don't know why though...

Comment: Please don't get into the habit of using comments like `//if statement starts` and `//call to print_result function`

Comment: Thanks for writing comments that aren't relevant to the problem. Also, I need those comments for credit.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look ok:

```
(*tailcpu)->next = temp2;
*tailcpu = temp2;
(*tailcpu)->next = NULL;
```

See what you're doing - the first assignment sets `(*tailcpu)->next` to `temp2`. From now on, you lost reference to whatever was in `(*tailcpu)->next`. Not only that, the next assignment (`*tailcpu = temp2`) destroys whatever you wanted to achieve with the previous assignment.

Comment: I don't know - the code you showed is not enough to provide further help. But revising these 3 assignments might be a good start.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is put the head of the cpu queue at the back (tail) of the cpu queue, if that's any help.

Comment: @Michformer Hum. My bad. In that case, this piece of code looks OK. Out of context, it looked dangerous, but now that you explained it, it makes sense. Sorry for misleading you

Comment: I just discovered the source of my problem. It's in the else statement. Apparently, something is preventing my results from printing properly.